# flask discord api error {"message": "401: Unauthorized", "code": 0}

Tags: python-3.x, api, flask, discord

Code that logs in from flask as discord oauth2 and receives logged-in user information.
However, log-in is successful only under few discord accounts.
The rest of the accounts have 401 errors like that.

I don't know why I can only log in properly from Few accounts and not from another.

my flask code :

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, redirect, session
from oauth import Oauth

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return redirect(Oauth.discord_login_url)

@app.route("/login")
def login():
    code = request.args.get("code")
    access_token = Oauth.get_access_token(code)
    user_json = Oauth.get_user_json(access_token)
    username = user_json.get("username")
    
    return username

if(__name__ == "__main__"):
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

oauth.py :

```
import requests


class Oauth(object):
    client_id = ...
    client_secret = ...
    scope = "email"
    redirect_uri = "http://192.168.35.5:8080/login"
    discord_login_url = f"https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&response_type=code&scope={scope}"
    discord_token_url = "https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token"
    discord_api_url = "http://discord.com/api"

    @staticmethod
    def get_access_token(code):
        payload = {
            "client_id": Oauth.client_id,
            "client_secret": Oauth.client_secret,
            "grant_type": "authorization_code",
            "code": code,
            "redirect_uri": Oauth.redirect_uri,
            "scope": Oauth.scope,
        }
        headers = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
        acces_token = requests.post(
            url=Oauth.discord_token_url, data=payload, headers=headers
        )
        print(acces_token)
        print(acces_token.text)
        json = acces_token.json()
        return json.get("access_token")
    @staticmethod
    def get_user_json(access_token):
        print(access_token)
        url = Oauth.discord_api_url + "/users/@me"
        data = {
            "scope": Oauth.scope
        }
        headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"}
        user_object = requests.get(url=url, data=data,  headers=headers)
        print(user_object)
        print(user_object.text)
        user_json = user_object.json()
        return user_json
```

print :

```
<Response [200]>
{"access_token": "rE2pOOJLn2rhpCxyEaKuYko0UDOG7N", "expires_in": 604800, "refresh_token": "HMSTtbeKXIbwSvrubBQfw9nkHu9cyu", "scope": "email", "token_type": "Bearer"}
rE2pOOJLn2rhpCxyEaKuYko0UDOG7N
<Response [401]>
{"message": "401: Unauthorized", "code": 0}
```

test in ubuntu shell:

```
root@localhost:~# curl --location --request GET 'http://discord.com/api/users/@me' --header 'Authorization: Bearer RV41u
drW040OZGzzZO3rvI1hVyZO4n'

# this account is working

{"id": "349781935196995585", "username": "Obtuse triangle", "avatar": "d57820246e2726d6b0f703ff216252d9", "discriminator": "5343", "public_flags": 64, "flags": 64, "banner": null, "banner_color": null, "accent_color": null, "locale": "en-US

root@localhost:~# curl --location --request GET 'http://discord.com/api/users/@me' --header 'Authorization: Bearer rE2pOOJLn2rhpCxyEaKuYko0UDOG7N'

# but this account is working

{"message": "401: Unauthorized", "code": 0}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Discord's documentation:

> Returns the user object of the requester's account. For OAuth2, this requires the `identify` scope, which will return the object without an email, and optionally the email scope, which returns the object with an email.

Try adding the `identify` scope to your token request

Comment: I cleared the values of several variables to raise the question.

Comment: You also have a typo in `acces_token = ...`

Comment: Yes, I have modified this.

Comment: ```Try adding the identify scope to your token request```
this is here? 
data = {
            "scope": ["identify", "guilds"]
        }

Comment: [link](https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/issues/3703)
I think it's the same problem.